# Converting a matrix column to a vector fails for reason unknown

Tags: r, geosphere

I'm working with output data from geosphere::gcIntermediate which generates Great Circle waypoints. The output is a list. I then establish the lengths of individual list items:

```
library(geosphere)
from = data.frame(lon = sample(-180:180,5), lat = sample(-90:90,5))
to = data.frame(lon = sample(-180:180,5), lat = sample(-90:90,5))
plot(gcIntermediate(from, to, n=30, breakAtDateLine=T, sp=T))
gcs = gcIntermediate(from, to, n=30, breakAtDateLine=T, sp=F)
print(gcs)
l = lapply(gcs, length)
```

But it seems impossible to convert this list into a simple vector. Anything I try yields either a list or a matrix of dimensions [100,1], for instance:

```
as.matrix(l)[,1]
as.vector(l)
```

Does this data have a somehow different internal structure despite being a matrix?  e.g. compare it to:

```
m = as.matrix(1:10)
m[,1]
```

Grateful for assistance.

Comment: I don't understand what this output is. Is it a list of matrices or a list of vectors? Perhaps you could do `dput(l)` to show us (or just `dput(l[1:2])` if that is too long?)

Comment: Also, try `sapply(l, class)` to see what type of objects you have.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what about `l.vector <- unlist(l)` ?

Comment: Actually both @Carl-Witthoft and @roman-lustrik's (as `do.call("cbind", l)[1,]`) solve this one. I wasn't aware of these techniques, so thanks chaps.  The reason for needing the vector is to filter the list, because the shorter elements are where Great Circle paths cross the 180th meridian and are cut into 2 sublists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cbind` or `rbind`, depending on what you're after. If this answers your question, please amend your question title to reasons known. :)

```
> do.call("rbind", l)
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   60
[3,]   60
[4,]   60
[5,]   60
> do.call("cbind", l)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

[1,]    2   60   60   60   60
```